# Using a linked list to read in images/text files in Java

Tags: java, swing, list

I am working on a student project for my programming module in which we have to build a project to incorporate a number of different Java features, mainly GUI design and advanced data structures, so am working on a system for students training in Java, where they will register with the system, take different tutorials in Java and sit tests. Am now stuck on one of the tutorials as I thought it would be a good idea, rather than have multiple pages going through the tutorial that the images and content within a tutorial would be updated on that page as the user hit "next" button or "back" button. So all the names of the images and text files would be stored in a linked list (so are in the right order) and the tutorial would start on an index of 1 (the start) so image 1 and content 1 would be displayed, as the user hit next the index would increment by 1 and the image and content would be updated. 
I am currently getting an error message of

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at gui.Tutorial1page1.imageSelect(Tutorial1page1.java:66)
at gui.Tutorial1page1.<init>(Tutorial1page1.java:69)
at gui.Tutorial1page1$1.run(Tutorial1page1.java:39)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions of where to start looking or if it is even not possible would be much appreciated. Should probably also mention the whole thing was working with just reading in the images before I added the linked list. Thanks :-)

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Tutorial1page1 extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Tutorial1page1 frame = new Tutorial1page1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

//declare the linkedlist for the images
private LinkedList<String> imageContent;

//declare int for the index of what image to select
//this will increase by one when user hits next button & decrease for back button
int index = 1;

//store the names of the files in order, add last will add them to end of list
public void Images()
{
    imageContent = new LinkedList<String>();
    imageContent.addLast("\"IfStatement.png\"");
    imageContent.addLast("\"IfElseStatement.png\"");
}

//select image
public String imageSelect(int index)
{
return imageContent.get(index);
}

String image = imageSelect(index);
/**
 * Create the frame.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public Tutorial1page1() throws IOException {

    //create, format and locate jframe
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit program when framed closed
    setBounds(300, 75, 800, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    //create, format and position button for going back through pages of tutorial
    //should this be disabled on first page??
    JButton btnBack = new JButton(" < Back ");
    btnBack.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnBack.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    btnBack.setBounds(150,500,120,30);
    contentPane.add(btnBack);

    //create, format and position button for quitting the tutorial
    JButton btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
    btnQuit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnQuit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnQuit.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    btnQuit.setBounds(350,500,120,30);
    contentPane.add(btnQuit);

    //add button listener for Next button
    btnQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            dispose();//close current screen
            //open main screen
            try {
                Main frame = new Main(); 
                //open last page of tutorial, in this case main module page
                frame.setVisible(true);
                //open in centre of screen
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //create, format and position button for going forward through pages of tutorial
    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next > ");
    btnNext.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnNext.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnNext.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    btnNext.setBounds(550,500,120,30);
    contentPane.add(btnNext);

    //add button listener for Next button
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            dispose();//close current screen
            //open main screen
            try {
                Tutorial1page2 frame = new Tutorial1page2(); //open next page of tutorial
                frame.setVisible(true);
                //open in centre of screen
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //create, format and position help button on each page of tutorial
    //uses label appearance method to look like linked text
    JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
    btnHelp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnHelp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    btnHelp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    btnHelp.setBounds(740,0,50,50);
    contentPane.add(btnHelp);
    Login.labelAppearance(btnHelp);

    //import and position resized icon
    BufferedImage iconresized = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/gui/iconresized.png"));
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(iconresized));
    contentPane.add(picLabel);
    picLabel.setBounds(5,10,50,80);

    //create, format and position label for the Tutorial description
    //this will remain the same on all pages of this tutorial
    JLabel lblTutorial1 = new JLabel("TUTORIAL 1 - Composition : If, switch, while & for statements");
    lblTutorial1.setFont(new Font("Gisha", Font.BOLD, 22));
    lblTutorial1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    lblTutorial1.setBounds(60, 40, 675, 44);
    lblTutorial1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    contentPane.add(lblTutorial1);

    //create, format and position label for the title of this page
    //this changes on each page of each tutorial
    JLabel lblIntroductionT1 = new JLabel("Introduction - Select Statements");
    lblIntroductionT1.setFont(new Font("Gisha", Font.ITALIC, 15));
    lblIntroductionT1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblIntroductionT1.setBounds(20, 125, 300, 26);
    contentPane.add(lblIntroductionT1);


    //create new text field for displaying notes on the page
    //this will wrap text to the text field horizontally, but allow a vertical scroll bar
    //if the text goes on too long to fit the field vertically
    TextArea Content1 = new TextArea("", 4, 30, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    Content1.setBounds(20, 155, 400, 300);
    contentPane.add(Content1);
    //add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Content1.setEditable(false);

    //read in text file for content
    FileReader readtextfile = new FileReader("src/gui/Tutorial1content.txt");

    //open scanner
    Scanner FileReaderScan = new Scanner(readtextfile);

    //create sting Tut1content to store what is read in
    String Tut1content ="";

    //while there is another line in text file add it to string
    while(FileReaderScan.hasNextLine()){
        String temp = FileReaderScan.nextLine() + "\n";
        Tut1content = Tut1content + temp;

    }

    //add contents of string to the text area
    Content1.append(Tut1content);

    //close scanner
    FileReaderScan.close();


    //import and position the diagram to go with text
    //both should be parallel to each other

    //read in image
    BufferedImage IfState = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(imageSelect(index)));

    //set image in JLabel
    JLabel picLabel2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(IfState));
    //add border to picture
    picLabel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    //add to frame
    contentPane.add(picLabel2);
    //set bounds, location
    picLabel2.setBounds(450,155,300,300);

    //create and position progress bar so user can track where they are in tutorial

    JProgressBar tut1progressBar = new JProgressBar(0,5);
    tut1progressBar.setValue(1); //page 1 of 5
    tut1progressBar.setBounds(220, 550, 380, 14);
    contentPane.add(tut1progressBar);

    //add label to progress bar to show page number currently on
    JLabel lblProgress1 = new JLabel("Page 1/5");
    lblProgress1.setFont(new Font("Gisha", Font.ITALIC, 10));
    lblProgress1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblProgress1.setBounds(690, 540, 80, 26);
    contentPane.add(lblProgress1);
}
}
```

Comment: "Any suggestions of where to start looking" - I would start looking on line 6<s>1</s>6 of `TutorialPage1.java`. :)

Comment: @VivinPaliath: that's line 66 I think, but your idea is correct.

Comment: You have not called Images method which initializes your list

Comment: @MrD That would give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and not a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am mistaken, but nowhere in your code do I see you calling the `Images` method, which is what instantiates the `LinkedList<T>` and populates it. Since you are calling `.get` on a `null` reference, you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

On a different note, please follow Java naming conventions in your code (so method names and variables should be in **camelCase**).

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated. Line 66 changed to " return images.get(index);" now saying images cannot be resolved :-/ have I made an error in that as well

Comment: @user1836661 No, you were using the right collection (`imageContent`). The problem is that you haven't called the `Images` method anywhere to initialize your list.

Comment: Sorry still a little lost. changed the images to a public class and wrote  images imageContent = new images(); - am I heading in wrong direction. Sorry still pretty new to this and been looking at screen too long I think.

Comment: @user1836661 is `Images` a class? It didn't see to clear from the code. Well, the point is that you will need to initialize the `imageContent` collection before you use it.